# Connect Bluetooth audio transmitter to Windows or Android to record

Tags: windows-10, audio, android, bluetooth, audio-recording

I have a Bluetooth audio transmitter/receiver (Ugreen CM403). In the transmitting mode, it converts analog input audio signal from a minijack (e.g. from a tape player) and sends it to my Bluetooth speaker. I want to record the audio received from the transmitter. To do that, I would like to connect the transmitter to my laptop (Windows 10 21H2) or my Android phone.

Neither the laptop nor my phone shows the transmitter in Bluetooth devices when I enable the pairing mode. When I use it with the speaker, both devices pair automatically once I enable pairing modes. I can't find a way to do the same on Windows/Android. Is it possible? If not, is there some other way I can record the audio sent via Bluetooth?

Comment: I have a UGreen-60300 (ASIN: B099K591CG) and have the exact same issue.  I came very close using an old windows 10 pc with a very old bluetooth dongle and BAVNCO bluetooth transmitter (ASIN: B08DRMS57Y), where windows recognized the recording device but refused to connect, so I tried a brand new bluetooth 5.1 dongle and it didn’t even see the device. Argh!

Comment: ah, on mine, there is no switch to change the input between mic and line input, and when it is in transmit mode, the mic is the active input. :(